# How to know when CWnd's Create function was called?

Tags: mfc, message

I've wrote a class wrapping a grid controls.
I want to init the custom grid class when it is created by calling Create function.

Is there a way that i can catch the event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if CWnd:Create or Cwd:CreateEx is used, it is possible to catch the Win32 event with:

```
afx_msg int OnCreate(
   LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct 
);
```

See [CWnd::OnCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2017)

With the corresponding mapping:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyGrid, CWnd)
ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Attention: If your control is directly added on a dialog template by the designer (ie, using DDX), the function CWnd:.OnCreate() is not called.

In all cases, the following function is called at creation, after the Hwnd (handle of window) is initialized:

```
virtual void PreSubclassWindow( );
```

See [PreSubclassWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2017)

Best regards,
Alain