# MFC: Notification after a control is created

Tags: mfc, controls

I'm new to MFC.  I chose to create an office style MFC app through the wizard in VS2017.   I now want to extend CMFCShellTreeCtrl so I created another class with that as the base class. The basics are fine.   My issue is that I want to do something like:

```
whatever MyClass::FuncitonCalledAfterControlCreated(...)
{
  SetFlags(GetFlags() | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS);
  ModifyStyle(0x0, TVS_CHECKBOXES);
}
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out what virtual function to override or am I supposed to do one of those message mapping things?  I would guess that whatever it is, it would be common to all controls?  Anyway, what would be the appropriate function?

TIA!!

Comment: [How to know when CWnd's Create function was called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484861/4603670)

Answer (score 1):

If control is derived from `CWnd` a `WM_CREATE` is issued which can be directed to the control via a message map of:

`ON_WM_CREATE()`

And member function:

`afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);`

If on a dialog resource the WM_CREATE won't occur.  Some say you can use `PreSubClassWindow` but on a case of testing `Create()`, that call comes BEFORE the `CreateWindowEx` call so won't work for setting the TVS_CHECKBOX style.  I didn't try a CDialog with a tree control and check the call stack.

Comment: The [WM_CREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-create) message isn't sent *after* a control is created. It is sent *during* the process of creating a control. From the documentation: *"The message is sent before \[`CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow`\] returns."*.

Comment: "The window procedure of the new window receives this message after the window is created, but before the window becomes visible."

Comment: That's - unfortunately - not entirely true: *"If the application returns –1, the window is destroyed and the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function returns a NULL handle."* Regardless of that detail, for your specific needs, the `WM_CREATE` handler is an appropriate place to set the `TVS_CHECKBOX` style. For an in-depth explanation see [The TVS_CHECKBOXES style is quirky, which is a polite way of saying that it is crazy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171127-00/?p=97465).